# PHP MYSQL looking for a way to group rows with mutiple details and totals

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datatables, grouping

I wanted to separate Project Names by grouping then show the details. Based on my codes, it shows the details but just in one row. plus I dont have a the sum feature.

Output should be like this

```
                Month | Contract Amount | Investment | Expense
Project Name 1  
                 Jan  | $9000           | $9000      | $100
                 Feb  | $10000          | $5000      | $500
Total:                | $19000          | $14000     | $600
Project Name 2
                 Jan  | $50000          | $2500      | $10000
                 Feb  | $10000          | $5000      | $500
                 Mar  | $20000          | $4500      | $1500
Total:                | $80000          | $12000     | $1200
```

My Source code.

Project Name is "pn"

```
 <?php
 $pdo = Database::connect();

 $sql = 'SELECT *, tt_projects.name as pn, tt_projects.id
 FROM tt_client_project_binds
 INNER JOIN tt_projects
 ON tt_client_project_binds.project_id = tt_projects.id
 INNER JOIN rms_projects_budget
 on rms_projects_budget.project_id = tt_projects.id';

 $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->execute();

 $categories = array();
 while (($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)))
 {

     $category = $row['pn'];
     $categories[$category][] = date('F', strtotime($row['month']));
     $categories[$category][] = $row['pn'];
     $categories[$category][] = $row['Contract_Amount'];
     $categories[$category][] = $row['investment'];
     $categories[$category][] = $row['expense'];

 }

 ?>
 <html>
     <body>
 <?php
foreach ($categories as $category => $consumption)
     { 
 ?>  
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">

 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th>Month</th>
 <th>Contract Amount</th>
 <th>Investment</th>
 <th>Expense</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>

 <h4><?php echo $category; ?></h4>

 <?php
 foreach ($consumption as $details)
     {
 ?>
 <td><?php echo $details; ?></td>
 <?php
     }
 ?>
 <?php
     }
 ?>
     </body>
      </html>
```

I would greatly appreciate for you help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1. Don't use evil `SELECT *`. Name the columns you want. 2. See about table aliases. They make code easier to read and mean less typing.

Comment: Done, Thank you!

Comment: Can you briefly explain the table structure of tt_client_project_binds, tt_projects, rms_projects_budget?

Comment: Because from first glance, the tt_client_project_binds in your above sql and the table structure seems redundant, when you can simply just link tt_projects and rms_projects_budget

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here's a quick hack to get things running, there probably is a much better solution than mine, but this works. xD

PS: I'm under the assumption of the table structure is similar to the one I've set up at http://rextester.com/PJJML53507

And here's the output: http://rextester.com/HATU87511

```
<?php

 $pdo = Database::connect();

 $sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT p.name, group_concat('{"month":', pb.month,',"amount":[', pb.contract , ',', pb.investment, ',', pb.expense, ']}') AS detail,
    sum(pb.contract) AS sum_contract, sum(pb.investment) as sum_investment, sum(pb.expense) as sum_expense
    FROM tt_projects p
    INNER JOIN rms_projects_budget pb
    ON p.ID = pb.project_id
    GROUP BY p.name;
SQL;

 $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->execute();

 $rows = $stmt->fetchall();

// Output - added \n for better viewing, you can remove it.

echo "<table><thead><th></th><th>Month</th><th>Contract Amount</th><th>Investment</th><th>Expense</th></thead>\n";

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td colspan=4></td></tr>\n";
    $details = json_decode('{"detail":[' . $row['detail'] . ']}', true)['detail'];
    foreach($details as $detail) {
        $month = $detail['month'];
        echo "<tr><td></td><td>$month</td><td>" . implode("</td><td>", $detail['amount']) . "</td></tr>\n";
    }
    echo "<tr><td colspan=2>Total:</td><td>" . $row['sum_contract'] . "</td><td>" . $row['sum_investment'] . "</td><td>" . $row['sum_expense'] . "</td></tr>\n";
}

echo "</table>\n";
?>
```

The idea of the solution is to merge the detail expenses into a JSON code, and let the SQL do most of the work instead of PHP.

By using json_decode(), you can instantly format the months and amount into respective arrays, once that's done, you can pretty much do whatever you want.

I've also added the sum columns at the end just to be lazy to not writing another variable to store the sums.